# Finding the square root of a radical expression

Tags: trigonometry, radicals

I have this (not necessarily optimum) method for finding the value of sin $15^{\circ}$.
(Meant to be an application of Angle Bisector Theorem).

In a equilateral triangle with side length 1, draw the altitude to get two $30^{\circ}-60^{\circ}-90^{\circ}$ triangles
Then, in one of the $30^{\circ}-60^{\circ}-90^{\circ}$ triangles, draw the angle bisector again to get a $15^{\circ}-90^{\circ}-75^{\circ}$ triangle.

Apply the Angle bisector theorem to find that the side opposite $15$ degrees is $\dfrac{(2\sqrt{3}-3)}{2}$.
Combine with height $\dfrac {\sqrt{3}}{2}$ to get the hypotenuse squared as $6 \sqrt{3}$, which then has as its square root $\dfrac {(3-\sqrt{3})}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Apply sin = opp/hyp to get the usual formula for $\sin 15^{\circ}$.

I got $\sqrt{6-3\sqrt {3}}$ as $\dfrac{(3-\sqrt{3})}{\sqrt{2}}$ through trial and error.
Is there a systematic way of finding it?

Comment: Use mathjax for formatting

Comment: Are you asking how to prove $\sqrt{6-\sqrt 3}= \frac{3-\sqrt3}{\sqrt2}$? You can't prove this because this is not true.

Comment: Not all regular polygons (and so as trigonometric ratios) can be constructed by compass and ruler.  See [constructible polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_polygon) and [cut the knot](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/cos15.shtml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you mean

$\sqrt{6-\color{blue}{3}\sqrt3}=(3-\sqrt3)/\sqrt2.$

Suppose we are given two positive rational numbers $a,b$ and we seek $x,y$ such that

$\sqrt{a-\sqrt{b}}=\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}$

Then we will have the conjugate relation

$\sqrt{a+\sqrt{b}}=\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}$

And upon multiplication

$\color{blue}{\sqrt{a^2-b}=x-y}$

We can also square each of the conjugate equations and add those squared results. The radicals cancel and we end with

$\color{blue}{a=x+y}$

Now, **if $a^2-b$ is a perfect square**, then the left sides of both blue equations are rational numbers and we can simply solve these equations as a linear system for $x$ and $y$. For the problem at hand we have $a=6,b=27,\therefore a^2-b=9=3^2$ and this process will work. We get $x=9/2,y=3/2$ which matches the claim.